# Generating random divs multiple times on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

let me just give a quick story. I have made a page. (VERY simple - two divs with a different background image, see [here.](http://beauaugust.co.uk/Honeycomb/))

Anyway, I need to make it so that when a new page loads, the two divs that I have load in a random order over and over, filling the entire screen content. So there's no pattern of the first div and then the second, it's just randomly generated. Sort of like a huge grid, with the two divs repeated with no pattern.

My question is...is that possible? I assume I'd need to know PHP, but I have no knowledge of it.

Thanks guys, I appreciate all help!

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/uYPRq/

**jquery**

```
var div1 = '<div class="one">';
var div2 = '<div class="two">';

var len = 
    Math.floor(window.innerWidth/30)*Math.floor(window.innerHeight/30);

for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {   
    if ( Math.random() > 0.5 ) {
        $(div1).appendTo('body');
    }
    else {
        $(div2).appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

**css**

```
div.one, div.two {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    float:left;
}

div.one { background-color:#EBE1E4; }
div.two { background-color:#F0F5DF; }
```

**edit:**
changed `screen.availWidth` to `window.innerWidth`

Comment: +1 for filling up the page; too bad you use jQuery though. It's not that much harder with vanilla JS.

Comment: Nice, but how would I go about moving every other line's left margin in by 15px?

Comment: @beau - you may want to accept this answer and then post a followup one. kei answered your question correctly. not fair to add stuff on at the end =)

Answer (score 2):

Something [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/cQbAp/10/)?  Just loop through how ever many times you like and add elements in.

```
for (i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    var type1 = document.createElement("div");
    var type2 = document.createElement("div");
    type1.innerHTML = "div1";
    type2.innerHTML = "div2";
    type1.setAttribute("class", "type1");
    type2.setAttribute("class", "type2");
    document.body.appendChild(type1);
    document.body.appendChild(type2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No PHP needed. This can be done client-side using Javascript (Jquery might be easier).

Comment: Well I appreciate that - but how would I go about it? Thank you! :)