# make divs load multiple times on page randomly

Tags: jquery, css

let me just give a quick story. I have made a page. (VERY simple - two divs with a different background image, see [here](http://beauaugust.co.uk/Honeycomb/).)

Anyway, I need to make it so that when a new page loads, the two divs that I have load in a random order over and over, filling the entire screen content. So there's no pattern of the first div and then the second, it's just randomly generated. Sort of like a huge grid, with the two divs repeated with no pattern.

My question is...is that possible? I assume I'd need to know jQuery, but I have no knowledge of it. Can you please help?

Thanks guys, I appreciate everything!

Comment: They gonna be overlayed or side by side?

Comment: As long as their sizes are compatible so that they tile correctly, there is nothing difficult about it.

Comment: Maybe not entonio, but I'm not javascript knowledgable - hence why I'm here asking you lovely people for help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random divs multiple times on load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541655/generating-random-divs-multiple-times-on-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want they side-by-side, i just did it.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ravan/X3fMC/

How it wors: Get width and heigth of document, then with 2 loops (one for top, other for left) you clone 2 initial divs and append then to the page.

Comment: That is basically exactly what I want, but is it possible to make every other line have a margin of half the div width? Haha

Comment: SORRY! That's not what I meant. I should have been more specific. I meant from the left hand side. -25px margin so that it's out of line if you get my drift?

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the divs go off the screen so that we don't see any white space? :)

Answer (score 1):

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JMPv7/41/?

Comment: EXACTLY LIKE THAT! THANK YOU! Just one thing though - Is it possible to make it so that the second line is pushed to the left by half the height of the div? So that every other line is pushed across?